# fiware spagobi cockpit graphics not upgrade

Tags: fiware, spagobi, cockpit

All graphics in my cockpit are not updated, even though the data source dataset is scheduled to be updated every 1 minute, and checking in the bbdd the dataset is updated correctly every 1 minute...

my dataset config:
[image]

How can I see the updated graphics? maybe needs to change something in spagobi server or configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Cockpit uses a cache mechanism that permits to query datasets coming from different datasources while joining them but has nothing to do with the dataset's persistence. 
At this moment, there are two ways to get updated data while using cockpit:

1. by cleaning the cache using the button inside the cockpit itself;
2. by using the cache cleaning scheduling setting.

In the latter case, enter the Configuration Management as admin to change the value for

> SPAGOBI.CACHE.SCHEDULING_FULL_CLEAN

variable to HOURLY. This setting creates a job that periodically (every hour, which is the minimun) cleans the cache used by cockpits.